# Array of pointers pointing to 2-dimensional arrays

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, multidimensional-array, floating-point

I want to make an array of pointers, where each one points to a 2D array of floats. The 2D arrays are defined like this

```
float a[][2] = {{1,0.5},{2,0.5},{3,0.5},{4,0.5}};
float b[][2] = {{1,1},{5,1},{4,0.5},{3,0.5},{2,0.5},{8,1}};
float c[][2] = {{1,0.333},{1,0.333},{1,0.334}};
```

Each one has a different amount of rows, but always 2 columns. I also have a function where I send one of those arrays as an argument, and need to use some values in them. Let's say it's something like this (there are other things related to other values I need to use, but it's not too relevant to the question)

```
void take_values(float arr[][2]){
  printf("%f ", arr[0][0]);
  printf("%f ", arr[0][1]);
}
```

In main(), I've been using the function on each of the arrays like this

```
take_values(a);
take_values(b);
take_values(c);
```

I want to find a way to iterate that function over each array. I was thinking of making an array of pointers referencing each 2D array, but I don't know how to define and use it.

1. How can I define the array of pointers to each of the 2D arrays?
2. How can I send the 2D arrays as arguments in the `take_values` function, using that array of pointers?
3. How would I access the specific values of the arrays inside the `take_values` function? / Do I need to use pointers there as well or just keep it the way it is now?

Answer (score 2):

```
float (*ptrs[])[2] = {a, b, c};
```

which reads as

```
        ptrs           -- ptrs
        ptrs[]         -- is an array of unknown size
      (*ptrs[])        -- of pointers
      (*ptrs[])[2]     -- to 2-element arrays
float (*ptrs[])[2]     -- of float
```

and we initialize it with pointers to `a`, `b`, and `c`.

Your function definition would look like this:

```
void take_values( float (**ptrs)[2] )
{
  ...
}

int main( void )
{
  float (*ptrs[])[2] = {a, b, c};
  ...
  take_values( ptrs );
}
```

You'd index into each array as

```
ptrs[i][j][k]
```

in both `main` and `take_values`.

**How we get there:**

Each of the *expressions* `a`, `b`, and `c` will "decay" to type `float (*)[2]`<sup>1</sup>, so a pointer to each array could be declared as

```
float (*pt1)[2] = a;
float (*pt2)[2] = b;
...
```

etc.  We just declare an array of pointers to store all three.

You'd index into each array as

```
ptrs[i][j][k]
```

Remember that `a[i]` is defined as `*(a + i)`, so

```
*a == *(a + 0) == a[0]
```

This means that

```
(*ptrs[i])[k] == (*(ptrs[i] + 0))[k] == (ptrs[i][0])[k] == ptrs[i][0][k]
```

Thus,

```
(*(ptrs[i] + j))[k] == (ptrs[i][j])[k] == ptrs[i][j][k]
```

In `main`, since `ptrs` is an array of `T`, where `T` is "array of pointer to 2-element arrays of `float`", when you pass it to the function, it will "decay" to type "pointer to `T`", or "pointer to pointer to 2-element array of `float`".

In `take_values`, you're dealing with a pointer to a pointer, so

```
(**ptrs)[i] == (*(*ptrs + 0))[i] == (*ptrs[0])[i] == (*(ptrs[0] + 0))[i] == (ptrs[0][0])[i]
```

Note that you need a way to indicate how big the array of pointers is, and how many rows each of the arrays contains.

---

1. Except when it is the operand of the `sizeof` or unary `&` operators, or is a string literal used to initialize a character array in a declaration, an *expression* of type "N-element array of `T`" will be converted ("decay") to an expression of type "pointer to `T`" and the value of the expression will be the address of the first element of the array.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
float a[][2] = {{1,0.5},{2,0.5},{3,0.5},{4,0.5}};
float b[][2] = {{1,1},{5,1},{4,0.5},{3,0.5},{2,0.5},{8,1}};
float c[][2] = {{1,0.333},{1,0.333},{1,0.334}};

float (*arr[])[][2] = {a, b, c};

for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(arr) / sizeof(void *); i++) {
    take_values(arr[i]);
}
```

But of course now you would have to change the definition of `arr` to include any more 2D arrays you have (but you would have to do that regardless.)

So, for example, if you added another 2D array called `d`, then you would have to change the definition:

```
float (*arr[])[][2] = {a, b, c};
```

to this:

```
float (*arr[])[][2] = {a, b, c, d};
```

**NOTE: Be careful with this:**

```
i < sizeof(arr) / sizeof(void *);
```

**If you ever pass your array of 2D arrays around, it will decay to a pointer and this won't work.**